# How to store data from StreamingClient.filter() or .sample() from the Tweepy Module Twitter API v2

Tags: python, twitter, jupyter-notebook, tweepy

I want to store Tweets that have certain hashtags such as #cats for example. I can pull the 10 most recent Tweets by executing `client.search_recent_tweets(query="cats")`, but then when I set up an object from the `StreamingClient` class and I try to use the `.filter()` and `.sample()` method **I can't seem to get any data...**

I'm using a Juypter Notebook, and my code looks like this:

```
streaming_client = tweepy.StreamingClient(bearer_token=twitter_keys.bearer_token)
streaming_client.sample()
streaming_client.disconnect()
```

I don't know if I need to store what the stream is retrieving inside a variable or do something else. I've been rereading the Tweepy 4.9.0 documentation but I can't find anything online that seems to answer my question, not to mention when I run the `filter()` and `sample()` methods my kernel just keeps running. I'm just confused.

Answer (score 3):

> By default, only [`StreamingClient.on_response()`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.9.0/streamingclient.html#tweepy.StreamingClient.on_response) logs the data received, at the `DEBUG` [logging level](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#levels).
>
> To customize the processing of the stream data, [`StreamingClient`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.9.0/streamingclient.html#tweepy.StreamingClient) needs to be subclassed.

https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.9.0/streaming.html#using-streamingclient